# Simple Service Bus not happy replying after the handler has completed

Tags: c#-4.0

I am using the Simple Service Bus from Codeplex and have a handler that provides me with a message and an IMessageContext.

```
public void Handle(MyEnquiryMessage message, IMessageContext context)
```

I store both these in a list and let the handler complete. At some point in the future I do some processing and try to send a reply by taking the context that I stored and calling:

```
 context.Endpoint.MessageBus.Reply(myResponse)
```

Unfortunately this throws an exception “Object reference not set to an instance of an object”. Is this asynchronous way of replying possible or can “reply” only be used within the handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Simple Service Bus but I would guess that your context is only valid in the handler.  If you want to send back a response you need to gather all the data you need from the context and simply do a 'send' at that later stage.

Even so, it sounds a bit strange performing process 'later' when it could probably be handled in another endpoint that processes a relevant message type.  Without more information it is difficulty to tell, but your design may not be optimal.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The reason that the messages are handled at a later time is due to them being passed to various tcp client in a priority order. As the clients may be busy or offline I have to store the messages and move on so not to block. I used the NService bus tag as I couldn’t find one for Simple Service Bus. It is a fork off the NService bus project so not completely off topic. If someone wants to down vote because of that then so be it. I don’t have the time for people that do such things. Thanks again for you advice, I will look again at the design of my application.